# Convert alert, prompt and confirm to UI Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert, prompt, confirm

I have a game that runs off of alerts, confirms and prompts to run the interface. I realized that this is not the best way to do this, and since I have no idea how to use jQuery and I don't have the time to go through and edit the whole thing, I could just convert it.

I found one script below that converts alerts for me, but how do I do the same thing for prompts and confirms?

**jQuery:**

```
 window.alert = function(message) {
     $('<div />').text(message).dialog({
        modal:true,
        title:'Message',
        buttons: {
           'OK':function(){
              $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        },
       close:function(){ 
         $(this).dialog('destroy').remove(); 
       }
   });
};
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="overrideAlert"></div>
```

Comment: have you tried anything yourself already?  like changing window.alert to window.confirm for example?  would be good to know what options you have exhausted

Comment: Pay attention to the fact that window.alert and window.confirm are blocking, while your redefinition of them will not be.

Comment: I'd suggest not overriding window.alert confirm and prompt, because you can't possibly create a function that will function in the same way with a custom dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I tryed it some time ago and just uploaded as [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/bitifet/eeefce6f97de2229b5c1).

But BE AWARE: Even your alert() implementation IS NOT fully equivalent to native window.alert() implementation because you can't stop javascript internal loop (see comments in my code).

This can cause severe issues using alert() replacements and make confirm() and prompt() implementations (I think totally) impossible.

**EDIT:** Konstantin Dinev solution will NOT work because his confirm() function will exit instantly (returning undefined) just like your alert() implementation (sorry, I can't comment his post directly).

...I was thinking about it time ago (but didn't implemented yet) that a better solution is NOT to redefine alert(), confirm() and prompt() and replace it by other implementation, **based in callbacks** (what implies you should modify your code a bit), which implement it with jquery and, optionally, failback (if you want) to window dialogs based implementation if jquery is not available.

Answer (score 0):

For confirm it should be pretty much the same. Try this code:

```
window.confirm = function(message) {
     $('<div />').text(message).dialog({
        modal:true,
        title:'Message',
        buttons: {
           'OK':function(){
              $(this).dialog('close');
              return true;
            },
           'CANCEL': function () {
              $(this).dialog('close');
              return false;
            }
        },
       close:function(){ 
         $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
         return false;
       }
   });
};
```